# Unfollow Twitter Profile PHP Script Not Working

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm not able to unfollow accounts. The code is returning the account details of user whom I want to unfollow.
Application is created by Account A, with read/write/Access Direct Messages.
I have logged in with a Account B, authenticated and returned back. Using below code I want to unfollow.

```
$key=$twitter_id_whom_i_want_to_unfollow; 

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    'consumer_key' => YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY,
    'consumer_secret' => YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$postfields = array(
        'user_id' => $key
            );
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/destroy.json'; /*Remove that user from friends*/
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$profile=$twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->setPostfields($postfields)
         ->performRequest();
$profile=json_decode($profile); 
echo '<pre>';print_r($profile);
```

This prints `$twitter_id_whom_i_want_to_unfollow` account details. Not able to understand how to deal with it. I'm developing a web app like [crowdfire](https://web.crowdfireapp.com/)

If I use same script to unfollow from `$twitter_id_whom_i_want_to_unfollow` account, it works, but not from any other account.

Comment: Are you sure this is not working? because this API endpoint returns the user object when it is successful.
Also note that "Actions taken in this method are asynchronous and changes will be eventually consistent."

Read carefully if in doubt: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/destroy

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure about it. I think its something related to access tokens.

Comment: make sure you are using account B's access token and secret to sign the request, not account A's that you got from application settings page. Twitter sends the access tokens and secret for account B to your oauth callback URL after account B grants access to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Found the solution. The above script is perfectly working, issue was with the access tokens, which were not being saved. Its fine now.